# Date_time format does not recognise AM/PM

Tags: excel, datetime, time

I have the following time series dataset from ebuttons.
When I extracted something wrong happened and in most of the data of each buttom I get some times formatted as follows

[image]

I have tried several things

1)= text(cell number , "hh:mm:00) in excel 
2)I have also tried to separate date and time in excel by holding date constant
3)In rstudio I have used different function as   as.POSIXct(concrete$time_date, format = "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") and as.Date

But there is something really wrong as I get this when trying option 1 and 2 in excel:

[image]

I think the time AM/PM whatever I tried is recognized as a text. But I do not know what else to try after having change format in different ways.

I am working on MAC

I really appreciate our attention in advance,

Best
Mara

Comment: If your timestamp is in cell A1 and formatted as Text, you can use the formula `=DATEVALUE(A1)+TIMEVALUE(A1)` in a different cell to convert it to an Excel timestamp value. Just remember to format that cell to show it the way you want. If you want it in the same format, then use a Custom Number Format of `m/d/yy h:mm:ss AM/PM`.

Comment: Hi  Peter , thanks for this. However, did not work ... unfortunately. I still get error . Now after formatting all as you suggested and using the formula I get a VALUE error

Answer (score 0):

Considering A1 as the first cell with data, try this one:

1. Select column B and give format as short date in the way you need.
2. Select column C and give format as Hour in the way you need.
3. On A2 place formula `=MID(A1,1,8)` (Maybe instead of 8 is 9, but check your data)
4. On A3 place formula `=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,9,20))`
5. Drag the formulas down.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I check your sample and it works. Dis you format the cells before placing the formula?